# Formatting number with a bunch of zeroes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

Somewhat simple problem:

I need to turn a column A, which contains numbers with up to 1 decimal (20, 142, 2.5, etc.) to a string with a specific format, namely 8 whole digits and 6 decimal digits but without the actual decimal period, like so:

```
1 = 00000001000000
13 = 00000013000000
125 = 00000125000000
46.5 = 00000046500000
```

For what it's worth, the input data from column A will never be more than 3 total digits (0.5 to 999) and the decimal will always be either none or .5.

I also need for Excel to leave the zeroes alone instead of auto-formatting as a number and removing the ones at the beginning of the string.

As a makeshift solution, I've been using `=CONCATENATE("'",TEXT(A1,"00000000.000000")),` then copying the returning value and "pasting as value" where I actually need it.

It works fine, but I was wondering if there was a more direct solution where I don't have to manually intervene.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=TEXT(A1*1000000,"0000000000000")` I think that's what you mean.

Comment: I think this is correct! I had to add one more zero to the 100000. Will have to test later. Can't believe it was so simple and didn't think of that. I feel dumb! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I must've gotten dizzy from counting zeroes. Fixed it in the answer.